# Find the elements that start with class using jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following list of elements.

```
 <tr id="level_0">
 <tr class="level_0_1">
 <tr class="level_0_2">
 <tr class="level_0_2_1">
 <tr class="level_0_2_2">
 <tr class="level_0_2_3">
 <tr class="level_0_2_3_1">
 <tr class="level_0_2_3_2">
```

I am trying select all the elements that have `class` `level_0_2_X` and not `level_0_2_X_X`

Using the jQuery "starts with" selector I am able to select all the elements that have `class` `level_0_2_X` and `level_0_2_X_X`

```
   $("tr[class^='level_0_2_']").show();
```

Comment: Please be careful when posting questions.  You kept referring to your `class` as `id`.  I edited it accordingly to match your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd better combine a selector with a filtering function :

```
$('[id^=level_0_2_]').filter(function(){ return this.id.split('_').length<5 })
```

If what you want is in fact a filtering on the class, you may use this :

```
$('[class^=level_0_2_]').filter(function(){
    return this.className.split('_').length<5
})
```

Comment: doh, you beat me to it . +1

Comment: Another bikeshed here...:)

Comment: The question isn't clear as it mix id and class. Maybe an adjustment would be needed.

Comment: @dystroy It throws TypeError: this.classname is undefined. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `match()`. Following must get the job done for you:

```
$('tr').each(function(){
     if( $(this).attr('id').match(/pattern/) ) {
          $(this).show();
     }
  }
```

Just use the pattern as required. Also above I have used 'id', you get the 'class' attribute if required and match against that.